# Why doesn't Ruby support GTK+ 2.14 and newer versions?

Tags: ruby, gtk

My application requires a GUI, and I was thinking of using GTK+ because by far it is the best library for Graphical User Interface. When I looked at the [GTK+ page](http://www.gtk.org/) and went to [Language Bindings](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php), I found the following:

[image: GTK+ Language Bindings - Why Ruby, why?]

If Ruby is a good language and has a lot of programmers, why doesn't Ruby support GTK+ 2.14 and newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because bindings to a more recent versions hasn't been yet written ? ;-)
Ruby-GNOME project is probably the most known implementation, see [status of Gtk2](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Status+of+Ruby%2FGTK). They also provide bindings for Gtk3, version 3.4 .
The differences between 2.12 and 2.24 are relatively marginal, there is no point it should you keep back at writing Gtk2 UIs in Ruby. The project is very [active](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2), latest commits was done a day ago.

Btw. linking on Linux/BSD systems is done to the major version so it'll run regardless minor subversion is currently installed. If there is some very specific feature added in latest versions you can write binding yourself, it's very easy. However as you are just at *learning* stage I'd bet you'll ever get in such situation in the near future.

Comment: I object against your claim that ruby-gtk is very active. It does update once in a while, but most of the time it is just adding a new description to the manual. In the past, I had spent years figuring out how to do things with it, but it turned out that I wasted a lot of time with it.

Comment: @sawa It got more doc updates in the last weeks however updates to the code are also relatively frequent. https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/commits/master?page=4 and [commits graph](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/graphs/commit-activity). What pitfalls did you met to judge it as a *waste of time* ?

Comment: It is too buggy, it easily segvs. The API is horrible. Interface with multimedia formats if limited. It is a crap. After years of its existence, there is no single practical application written in ruby-gtk. The few apps that they show as demos are the best you can do with it.

Comment: @sawa I've got sigsegv with gtkpixpuf only. I didn't do too much with ruby-gnome, just some frontends and config GUI for our app and the experienci is just ok.

Comment: What you recommend to GUI interfaces using Ruby, @sawa ?

Comment: There is no good GUI library on Ruby. That is a weakness of Ruby.